# Symfony2 in prod can see code changes

Tags: symfony, production-environment

I noticed if I changed the source code, it affects the production environment. Is this behaviour normal?

I suppose regenerating cache on file change should only happen in dev environment and changes to the source code should not apply in prod cache.

This is my app.php file:

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This is my config_prod.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        strict_requirements: null
```

and config.yml :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: databases.yml }

framework:
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig','php']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
```

I clear the cache with this command :

```
app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct behaviour: what isn't a correct behaviour is to update file directly where your production environment is. I mean, you should have those env. physically separated

Comment: Yes I know I shouldn't edit the code in prod environment. I think checking for source changes is not necessary in prod environment. Is it possible to turn it off?

Comment: I suppose that isn't possible, but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

It will affect both environments as they are not environments but more like modes. You can execute your changes in dev mode or production mode but regardless the code will effect both modes of dev and production. Dev mode just lets you view stats, logs etc along with debug messages which you may not want to show in production mode.